# Function $g=0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere meaning?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading about the measure theory, where I came across the term $\mu$-almost everywhere.
The instruct teaching the course says;

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $g:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $g(\omega)=0, \ \forall \omega\in\Omega$, $\mu$-almost everywhere. Then,
$$\int_{\Omega}g(\omega)d(\mu)=0.$$

What I don't understand is, what did he mean by $g=0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere?
Would anybody care to shed some light on it?

Comment: I can't believe this definition has not been given in your course and is not in the textbook either. I recommend reading the textbook. That's old fashioned but it is so much better for learning.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro ; I agree with you that I should read a book. But believe me I don't even have money to eat properly. My economic condition is very bad at the moment. I am learning measure theory through the internet based resources.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: It's possible the OP is confused about the usage of "$\forall \omega \in \Omega$" as I explain more fully in a comment to Nicolas Agote's answer.

Comment: @RobinKurtz: I'm sorry to hear that. Good luck with your studies. Terence Tao has an online book which is free to download: https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf Hope this helps

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro ; Thanks for your help! I would look into that book.

Answer (score 2):

What $\mu$-almost-everywhere means is that the set where the condition is not met has $\mu$-measure $0$. In this case, this would mean that $\{\omega \in \Omega | g(\omega)\neq0\}$ satisfies that $$\mu(\{\omega \in \Omega | g(\omega)\neq0\})=0$$ (note that the set will be measurable because $g$ is $\Sigma$-measurable).

As in your example, many properties will hold for functions which are equal $\mu$-almost-everywhere and such it will probably be a recurring hypothesis for some theorems or properties. This condition is also part of what makes the measure-theoretic approach more flexible than for example the Riemann integral approach, as it allows for more general exceptional sets. As a further example, if we consider $\mathcal{L}$ the Lebesgue measure over $(\mathbb{R}, \beta(\mathbb{R}))$, then the Dirichlet function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 &\text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0&\text{ if } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
is a function that is equal to $0$ $\mathcal{L}$-almost-everywhere.

**Edit (just adding what @Dave L. Renfro insightfully uncovered)**

There may have been some confusion arising from the use of both: $g(\omega)=0$ $\forall \omega \in \Omega$ and $g=0$ $\mu$-almost-everywhere. These are usually not equivalent: for example the Dirichlet function is a function that is $0$ almost-everywhere but is not equal to $0$ for every value in its domain. Actually, the function being $0$ when evaluated for every element in its domain is stronger than it being $0$ $\mu$-almost-everywhere because in such case the set $\{\omega \in \Omega | g(\omega)\neq0\}$ is the empty set which will always have measure $0$.

Then if a function $g$ satisfies both $g(\omega)=0$ $\forall \omega \in \Omega$ and $g=0$ $\mu$-almost-everywhere, we can just assume it is the (constant) zero function as it is the only function that satisfies both.

That being said, the property that was mentioned from the textbook,
$$\int_\Omega g(\omega) d\mu(\omega) = 0$$
is actually true not only for the (constant) zero function but for functions that are equal to zero $\mu$-almost-everywhere. This is why it would make sense for the author to just ask for the weaker $g=0$ $\mu$-almost-everywhere instead, but in such case we usually just write:

$g=0$ $\mu$-almost-everywhere

(or $g=0$ almost-everywhere when it is clear with respect to which measure) instead of:

$g(\omega)=0$, $\forall \omega \in \Omega$, $\mu$-almost-everywhere.

To sum up, there may have been an unfortunate use of notation, but the usual broader context in which the property is true is that of functions that are equal to the (constant) $0$ function $\mu$-almost-everywhere and that would be the way I would suggest to interpret the notation.

Comment: It's possible that @Robin Kurtz's concern might be the inclusion of "$\forall \omega \in \Omega$" in "$g(\omega)=0, \ \forall \omega\in\Omega$, $\mu$-almost everywhere", and not what "$\mu$-almost everywhere" means. Obviously "$\forall \omega \in \Omega$ we have $g(\omega) = 0$" IMPLIES "for $\mu$-almost everywhere we have $g(\omega) = 0$", so why say it holds $\mu$-almost everywhere in $\Omega$ if we already know it holds for all $\omega \in \Omega$? I think the author is a bit too concise (or careless, not thinking enough about how what is written could be misinterpreted), **(continued)**

Comment: and the author means that the function $f$ is defined for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and, for $\mu$-almost everywhere in $\Omega,$ we have $f(\omega) = 0.$

Comment: Thanks @DaveL.Renfro! I have added your insight to the answer.